# Using Microsoft Live as an OpenID option to an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, openid

Coding Platform: ASP.NET 4.0 with C#

Building a website using ASP.NET membership(forms authentication) and options to link Open IDs to it. I would like to have Microsoft Live as an OpenID option in this website. Well I have not seen Login using Windows Live ID except at forums.asp.net, but then both are Microsoft websites.

Today, I stumbled upon a website that seems to be using Microsoft Live Connect or whatever. I tried searching for it but I couldn't get any documentation regarding an API for Live Connect.

Here's the URL: http://messengerconnectidentity.mslivelabs.com/

Has anybody used this / will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement Windows Live ID, you must register your Web site with Microsoft® as an application and receive a client ID for use with the service. Only a person who has a valid Windows Live ID can register an application and obtain a client ID. After you create the application, you can sign in and change it whenever you want.

details on;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676626.aspx

also have a look at this;

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/08/17/integrate-windows-live-id-authentication-into-your-website.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've just heard about this on a live seminar, which spoked for OpenId and Windows Live. Have a look at http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/openid/ which may be a direction to point this issue?

Comment: No. I would like a direct API with live. Thank you for your help :)